# How to check whether a web server has SSL or not

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, wkwebview

I am developing a small web browser application using WKWebView. There, when the user enters the url I want to check whether the relevant web server has SSL and then redirect to the https:// one.

For an example user enters http://facebook.com. 
Since facebook has SSL, I want to redirect the user to https://facebook.com

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edited: My fault. It is done by website itself. I misunderstood some stuff.**

Comment: If you're writing your own from scratch for real world use, you should also look into HSTS too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security
But if this is just a home work question, please be more specific about how/why/what you are stuck on making basic HTTP (of any kind) requests though the WebView.

Comment: @JonAdams yes this is for real world use. Thanks for the information. I am new to these kind of things. Tha's why. This is just to download images from internet into my application. It's a small kind of web browser. In chrome application when we put http: //someweb.tld, if the server has SSL, it redirects user to https: //someweb.ltd. I need to implement that behavior. If I need to be more specific please tell. Thanks for helping friend.

Comment: I don't think you should redirect that at all. There might be a reason to why the user want to get the website via HTTP. Also if a website want all their traffic over HTTPS they can make that redirection, which facebook in your example already does.

Comment: @ntoonio That means it is not the WKWebView but the website, does the thing?

Comment: @GMHSJ yeah exactly

Comment: @ntoonio thanks friend. now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't provide us with much details or restrictions, only you know what would best suit your needs with the below options.

**The Client-side naive approach**

- Strip away the protocol HTTP from the URL and replace it by HTTPS
- Make a HEAD call using the newly formed URL
- On receiving a positive response code (2XX), you could infer that HTTPS is available and do the redirect yourself

This solution comes at the cost of an initial call to "guess" the availability of HTTPS. On a positive outcome, you need to do another call to get the document.

**Predictive approach**

Predict that the website has HTTPS and request it right away. If the page doesn't return, you try again with HTTP. Of course, you make sure you don't show anything to the user until you are certain of the outcome of both requests. do not confuse this solution with the previous one. This solution tries to "load" the website right away where as the previous one "verifies" first.

**GET them all**

Since you are developing a browser from scratch, consider the possibility of getting both pages. GET both URLs with HTTP and HTTPS in a concurrent manner. Upon receiving a positive response for HTTPS, you show it. Otherwise, you only show the HTTP response (good or bad).

**Modern browser strategy**

Let the server decide by always using the provided URL. In doing so, if HTTP is not allowed, the server "should" alert you by answering with a redirect status code (3xx) and provide you with the new destination in the response header. This approach simplifies the client logic, but expect the server to send the redirect details. Be aware that not all website handles this case.

*Request example to http://www.gmail.com*

```
Request URL:http://www.gmail.com/
Request Method:GET
```

*Response Headers*

```
Status Code:307 Internal Redirect
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Location:https://www.gmail.com/
Non-Authoritative-Reason:HSTS
```

Comment: It was my fault. I didnt know that it is done by website itself. I misunderstood things. Thanks for helping friend.